# Enabling DHCP without being connected

Tags: installation, networking, dhcp

I was installing Ubuntu server the other night and I was not able to hook up to the network while installing because I don't have a monitor for my desktop machines. I had to go into the living room and connect to the HDTV instead. This leaves me without network connectivity.

When installing it asks how I would like to set up the network. I would like to enable DHCP but it tries to detect a gateway when I do this and obviously it doesn't find anything. It won't let me move on without setting up an IP manually at that point. Isn't there a way I can enable DHCP for the next time it boots up instead? Why the need for it right then and there?

Answer (score 2):

You could give bogus info for the initial setup, then once your system is installed, 
edit `/etc/network/interfaces` with something like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

(You'd replace `eth0` if it's different from your interface, of course.)